# Please recommend some works on criticism/critique of the Hindu scripture Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: ethics, theology, eastern-philosophy

Can someone recommend some scholarly works on critique / criticism of the Bhagavad Gita.

Specifically from its utilitarian and broad ethical framework perspectives.

Can it be said that just because Krishna has been depicted to be the God in the scripture, thus his arguments given in the Gita becomes binding on Arjuna (whom he advices and motivates for war as his righteous duty). Still, it seems the arguments are to be accepted just on the strength of Krishna's portrayed divinity and not on the pure philosophical merit of the argue era present.

The Indian Nobel Economics Prize Laureate, Amartya Sen has given a brief critique of the text, in what he calls deontological perspective thought on Gita.

I am looking for similar high grade scholarly analysis of the Gita.